# IE not running scripts i iframe

Tags: internet-explorer, dom

I have a small website and have been playing around with ajaxtabs. I have it working as I would like but I can't get the srcipts in the iframe to work in IE.

I am aware of this bug in IE and have been researching and trying everything to fix for a few days nows with no success.

here is the script:

```
http://103.11.206.202/~worldnei/ajaxtabs/ajaxtabs.js
```

Here is the webpage I am trying to get working:

```
http://103.11.206.202/~worldnei/portfolio.html
```

I know its a dom issue I just cant seem to get working.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Check for your ajax call, the selector you're using is "href", on the tabs you're using have empty href's, this way ajax can't load.

removing the "a" tag from your tabs and leave just the